# "MDS CPU bug present and SMT on" Bugs decteted after running JURNALCTL on opensuse leap 15.5 shell

Tags: linux-kernel, opensuse, cpu, bugs, cpu-architecture

Running JURNALCTL on opensuse leap 15.5 shell , it detected the following bugs:

1- MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.

2- MMIO Stale Data CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/processor_mmio_stale_data.html for more details.

3- #5 #6 #7

I had a look at the sites reported , but since I'm a simple linux user i can' t  understand really what is the bugs impact and what to do, if needed. Does someone have a simple solution to suggest like shell commands or something like that to solve it?